# Singleton time triggered Azure Function across multiple regions

Tags: c#, azure, concurrency, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I have a time triggered Azure Function deployed in multiple regions and I want to have singleton behavior across them. For example, if the regions are west US and central Europe, I want only one of them to run each time. Can this be achieved?

As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer#scale-out) says, TimeTrigger uses the Singleton attribute implicitly to ensure only one instance of a function is run per host, so that aspect is covered.

In order to have the same behavior in all regions, I tried using Singleton with the following parameters:

```
[Singleton(Account = "myAccount", Mode = SingletonMode.Listener)]
```

I tested it locally by copying my C# solution and running both projects. The following error was shown:

```
The listener for function 'MyFunction' was unable to start. 
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Storage: Must replace singleton lease manager to 
support multiple accounts.
```

I did not find information about the `Account` property more than from the metadata of the Singleton class, that says `Gets the name of the Azure Storage account that the blob lease should be created in`. I don't know how the function knows how to connect to the Storage and where to configure the connection.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the `Account` property of the `[Singleton]` attribute refers to the name of an app setting, not actually the name of your storage account. If not specified, it assumes the storage account specified by the `AzureWebJobsStorage` app setting. The app setting that you reference here will need to contain the full storage connection string.

Note that if you want *cross-region* singleton behavior, all copies of your app will need to use the same storage account (which obviously could live in some other region). I expect there will be some egress charges related to this, but hopefully not enough to have much impact. Something to be aware of, though.

UPDATE:

Regarding the error message you encountered, it turns out there's actually an issue with this feature in Functions 2.0. A new GitHub issue was recently opened which tracks the problem: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/2214. It also points to a temporary workaround, which is that you can register your own `IDistributedLockManager`implementation, as shown in the test code.

Comment: `all copies of your app will need to use the same storage account`  - this will create an instance for each region? doesnt make sense to me

Comment: I deployed two Function Apps working in service plan and using the same storage account in the `AzureWebJobsStorage` settings, but both are being triggered and executed at the same time. I tested it with different parameters in the Singleton attribute and without it (because it should be implemented automatically by TimeTrigger) with the same results. I guess the only solution now is to deploy only one copy of the Function app.

Comment: @MauriR Part of the blob lease path includes the unique Function App HostId, which by default is unique for each Function App. Likely this is why even though you're using the same storage account, both Timers are firing. If you look in your storage account you'll probably see the two different listener locks (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to#singleton-attribute)). Remove your explicit SingletonAttribute annotation, and ensure you're using the same HostId for both apps and it'll work.

Comment: @MauriR In Functions v2, you can specify HostId via an app setting `AzureFunctionsWebHost:hostId`. For Functions v1 you can specify the ID in host.json via the `hostId` property.

Comment: @mathewc Thank you. I can confirm that by specifying a host id the functions exclude each other. However, when I set the host id a warning is raised with this message https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/e8e711f29f015f7e5adb27b72486768ef311afc0/src/WebJobs.Script/Host/ScriptHost.cs#L284 This mutual exclusion works locally and in deployed functions.

Comment: It is important to mention that this does **not** work in consumption plan, and it doesn't raise an error. Only by looking at the logs I was able to know that both functions were running at the same time.