# Azure Function TimeTrigger in multiple regions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage

I want to run a fully redundant failover environment in Azure. I have my webapps covered with an Azure Traffic Manager. I can run my storage queues in two different accounts. All is covered. The only thing I can't figure out is how timetriggers should be handled? I can't have them fire in both regions. Does anyone here have an idea or solution I could try?

Comment: Good question, I'm not aware of anything Azure does to support this. How often does the timer trigger fire?

Comment: I got like 6 different triggers that initiate import of data so I would like to have them only trigger once.

Comment: Please see the post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56383684/singleton-time-triggered-azure-function-across-multiple-regions

Comment: @SillyJohn thanks. This could be the answer even though this is not a pure solution because you need a third region with an account. But it is better than all the hacks I have thought about.

Answer (score 0):

Time triggers will run only instance at a time even though you have configured for  multiple instances scale out. The timer trigger uses a storage lock to ensure that there is only one timer instance when a function app scales out to multiple instances. If two function apps share the same identifying configuration and each uses a timer trigger, only one timer runs.

Comment: This doesn't solve the question. You still need to take multiple locations into account.